# Effect of solid in equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

CaCO3 (s) = CaO (s) + CO2 (g)

We know that pure solids quantity doesn't affect the position of equilibrium. But the application of pressure in gas does.

If we add CaCO3 in the closed system, the position of equilibrium should change, shouldn't it?

If we add CaCO3 the concentration shouldn't increase but the pressure in closed system should increase. Then it should affect in CO2 because the pressure has been increased.

Then why this is told that that pure solids quantity doesn't affect the position of equilibrium?

Comment: You are saying that CaCO3 is added to a system of unchanged volume or mass/matter (except the given addition)?

Comment: Because we live in a world that is open, and most systems are under constant pressure, not constant volume.

Comment: I am saying about a system of unchanged volume.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to say *unchanged volume **and** unchanged mass/matter (except the given addition).*

Comment: I am asking simply that what should happen when i add CaCO3?

Comment: The reaction will go forward or backward?

Comment: @Zhe how can one observe equilibrium in a system that is under constant pressure not constant volume?

Comment: Yes! I was also thinking about that.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You see it all the time. You live in a world that is constant pressure and not constant volume.

Comment: @Zhe can you occur a reversible reaction without holding the volume constant? According to my knowledge reversible reaction can only be occured in a closed system where the volume is constant. If my knowledge is wrong then you inform me the right one. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Just ask yourself if reversible reactions happen in the real world because the real world is basically constant pressure.

Comment: I knew that reversible reaction can only be occured in a closed container, where the volume is constant. Now you are telling the other thing. If you give me some link about this or explain I will be pleased